# JS/HTML - Is an img cached when its source URL changes for the same img?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, image-loading

Using an img tag with a URL as the source will normally cache the image so it doesn't have to be reloaded. What however happens when the src URL to the image changes but still references the same image? Will the browser still use the cached version or will it fetch the new image everytime the URL changes?

Background of my question:
I'm saving my images on an AWS s3 bucket and I use presigned URLs to reference an image. Those URLs are generated on the fly and change constantly.

Comment: Browser caches are a mapping from URL strings to resources. If the URL changes, the browser has no way of knowing whether the data on the other side of the network is the same as some random other URL it fetched in the past.

Comment: Create the image dynamically from the url and display

Answer (score 0):

The browser will not know that two different URLs refer to the same image, so it won't use the cache. You can however program a ServiceWorker to return a cached image if you know that two different URLs refer to the same image.

```
const cacheName = 'cache-v1';

async function serveImage(request) {
  const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
  // If you know that request.url refers to the same image that was previously
  // available under a different URL:
  const equivalentURL = ...;
  const cachedResponse = await cache.match(equivalentURL);
  if (cachedResponse) {
    return cachedResponse;
  }
  // If there's no match in the cache, get the image from the network
  const networkResponse = await fetch(request);
  // If the network response is ok (status < 400), add it to the cache
  if (response.ok) {
    await cache.put(request, networkResponse);
  }
  return networkResponse;
}

self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  if (url.pathname.startsWith('/images/')) {
    event.respondWith(serveImage(event.request));
  }
  // If we don't call event.respondWith, the request 
  // will go to the network as normal
});
```

If you're new to Service Workers, [this web.dev article](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/service-workers/) provides a good overview, and MDN has [a very useful documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

Answer (score -2):

If the source image of your URL address changes, it can have several implications. For instance, if the image is used on a website, the website may display a broken image icon instead of the original image. This can lead to a poor user experience and may cause visitors to leave the website. Additionally, if the image is used in a search engine optimization (SEO) context, changing the URL of an image can negatively impact the SEO performance of a website 1.

In terms of detecting whether an image URL is broken or not, one way to do this is by using the file_get_contents() function in PHP and finding out its image type using getimagesize(). Only if getimagesize() returns a valid file type, can you rely that it is in fact a valid image 2.

I hope this helps!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).